# How can you make an Angular component same dimensions as its content?

Tags: css, angular, sass

So I have an Angular component, which does change its height depending on an input argument. Like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'x',
    templateUrl: './x.html',
    styleUrls: [ './x.scss' ],
})
export class xComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() bigVersion: boolean;

    constructor(
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

with something like this in the template:

```
<div [class.big]="bigVersion">

</div>
```

and this in the styling:

```
div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  &.big {
    max-height: 340px;
    height: 55%;
  }
}
```

But the component always shows with the dimensions 0x0 and doesn't flow with the page.

How can I make the component the same size as its content?

Using the following did not work:

```
:host {
    display: block; // or inline-block
}
```

Comment: The component selectors themselves like `<app-component>...</app-component>` are always `0x0`, but that doesn't influence the size of their content HTML.

Comment: yeah they are always 0x0 because they are `display: inline`. I would like to change that fact. It doesnt affect the contents HTML, but the outside ones it does. @RobinDeSchepper

Comment: I can't completely make up what you're trying to achieve, but I can almost guarantee you you're going about it the wrong way if you're trying to style these elements. Try placing some style where you use the component instead: `<x style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></x>`. That should effectively change the size of your component, but when you serve that you'll see that in the end HTML there'll still be the `0x0` element, but with either a child or parent element where Angular applied the required CSS